# Google Earth Engine: Same geometry different Areas (PERSIANN-MODIS)

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I was trying to count the number of pixels that are inside my ROI and differs quite a lot one image from the other.

For MODIS image I get a total of 265533 pixels (500x500) spatial resolution and for PERSIANN-CDR I get 75 in total (27000*27000). The total area for both are completely different. Does anyone know why?

```js
var image1 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD16A2/2001_11_17').select('ET');

var c = image1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry
  });

print(c);

var image2 = ee.Image('NOAA/PERSIANN-CDR/20011101').select('precipitation');

var c2 = image2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry
  });

print(c2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you are not specifying the `scale` argument. You need to use it to force EE to do it at the scale you want, look at this very sikilar thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/vI6grpVRLCs/rTNFyTImCAAJ

If you indicate the scale, you get a quite similar rsult for the area:

```js
var image1 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD16A2/2001_11_17').select('ET');
var image2 = ee.Image('NOAA/PERSIANN-CDR/20011101').select('precipitation');

var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-105.325, 37.679], [-105.356, 37.333], [-104.331, 37.4028],  [-104.328, 37.694]]]);

var c = image1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 500
  });

var c2 = image2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 27000
  });

print(c);
print(c2);
print(ee.Number(c.get("ET")).multiply(500).multiply(500));
print(ee.Number(c2.get("precipitation")).multiply(25000).multiply(25000));
```

For this random polygon, this gives:

- MODIS: 2699000000
- NOAA : 2500000000

Note: this might be a rough estimate however, as pixel area is not necessarily constant, depending on the projection used! One way to tweak this would be to use `ee.Image.PixelArea()`, or just `area(), see:

```js
var im_area_1 = ee.Image.pixelArea().reproject(image1.projection())

var sum_area_1 = im_area_1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geometry
  });

print(sum_area_1.get("area"), "sum_area_1")
print(geometry.area(), "true ")
```

Both numbers are very close, at 3153188563, but very different from the counts based on the first method!